# How to read data from a CSV into a tuple in Python?

Tags: python, csv, tuples

I'm attempting to load a CSV which looks like the following and create a tuple out of it, so that I can later access account1, account2, etc in code:

```
user,password
johndoe@gmail.com,password
janesmith@gmail.com,password2
```

So far, all I've been able to do is import the CSV.

```
import csv

# our csv file name
filename = "resources/accounts.csv"

with open(filename) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
```

I'm looking for something like so:
{("johndoe@gmail.com", "password"), ("janesmith@gmail.com", "password")}

Could someone advise on what to do from here?

Comment: Marcel: Just append each row (which will be a tuple of values) to a list.

Comment: @martineau Thanks. I was interested in turning them into a tuple instead of list due to the fact that it's immutable. Am I misunderstanding a fundamental concept here?

Comment: I don't think the immutability of a tuple is that useful in a useful like this.  Who would try to change it, by mistake or evil intent?

Comment: Marcel: You could create a tuple-of-tuples — i.e. `(('johndoe@gmail.com', 'password'), ('janesmith@gmail.com', 'password'))` — with: `tuple_of_tuples = tuple(row for row in csv.reader(infile))`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import csv # our csv file name 
filename = "resources/accounts.csv" 
with open(filename) as infile:
  reader = csv.reader(infile)

accounts = {"accounts" : []} 
for line in reader:
    accounts["accounts"].append({"user":line[0], "pass": line[1]})

print(accounts["accounts"][1]["user"])
```

Sorry I did this on mobile hope it shows up